# Form does not do anything (freezes) while an operation is busy

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms application using C#. I try to read some data from a file and insert it into a datatable. While this operation is busy, my form freezes and I can't event move it. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: its confusing what you trying to say.

Answer (score 10):

This might be because you do the operation on your UI Thread.

Move the File and Database actions to another thread to prevent your UI Thread from freezing.

Here is an example using the ThreadPool.
As an alternative you can manually start Threads but then you need to keep track of them manually if you e.g. want to abort them etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // With ThreadPool
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork);
      }

      private void DoWork(object state)
      {
         // Do Expensive Work
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
         }
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DoWork finished!");
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). i.e.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoAction()).ContinueWith(() => DoAfterActionIsComplete());
```

Comment: Teoman kardeş teşekkür ederim, ama kodunu bir az açıklar mısın, lütfen.

Comment: I get an error when I try this: `Delegate 'Action<task>' does not take 0 arguments` But when I remove the `DoAfterActionIsComplete()` this works for me. +1 This is the only answer I have been able to correctly implement.

Answer (score 2):

Your UI related controls run on `UI thread` and as a rule, you should not do time consuming work on your UI thread (if you do that, your UI thread will block/freeze until that task completes).
There is another type of thread called `Worker Thread` which you can create and use to do long running tasks which would keep your UI responsive/not freeze.

Alternatively, there is a `Backgroundworker component` in Winforms, which you can utilize to do tasks on non-UI thread, which is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using the main thread to do operations that take long time. Best solution is to use another thread for making the reading of the file you need and this will allow the main thread to be updated normaly. 
Read here more about threads http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx